# Python Tesseract OCR training to a specific list of words

Tags: python, string, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am quite new to OCR and to Tesseract.

So far I have a working script that is extracting fairly good text from images.

My doubt: is possible to train tesseract to retrieve only words/chars presented in some kind of dictionary file??

For example, I have an .txt with a big list of person names, and I want to train Tesseract that "SONIA" is not "50NlA" and "YANNICK" not "VANNlD", etc...

If it has a list of all possible names it will be able to give better accuracy? If the original image is a text with a lot of person names, and other information about that persons, but I want only to retrieve names from ocr and ignore the "noisy information", what can I do? Sorry if it is a stupid question.

I have read this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/r5qkHxQOT98 and the manual http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html and created the eng.user-words and the bazaar files... what should be the next step? Since it gives me same outputs...

Thanks so much for your time and patient.

Comment: So basically, whenever you encounter "50NlA", you want to store it as "SONIA" (which is already trained), right?

Comment: I gess so, yes, since I have a list of correct names!... I have read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599768/tesseract-ocr-recognize-complete-dictionary-words-only about the bazaar but did not understand it quite well

Comment: it is a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348214/tesseract-training-only-few-words

Comment: What you could do is that you can train your data with your words, but while checking you can compare the words based on their Levenshtein distance (to measure how similar two words are). If you find similarity, go ahead with the word in training data, else update it. Read more about Levenshtein distance here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: @InêsMartins Does Tesseract give you a probability distribution for each recognized character or only a string for the complete document?

Comment: @moose it gives me only one sting for the complete document

Comment: @InêsMartins I think in this case you will not have any really good possibilities. The suggested Levenshtein distance might be the best.

Comment: but in manual http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html i followed it and it says to create the eng.user-words and the bazaar files